# mypy class forward references in type alias gives error when in other module

Tags: python, mypy

I want to keep my type aliases in one module, say `my_types`, to be able to
use them anywhere in my application (similar to the standard `typing` module).
But mypy complains that the forward reference to class `X` is not defined.
If I define class `X` later in that same module, it’s okay, but if it defined
in another one, mypy gets upset.

So my question is, how do I keep all my type aliases in one module
without mypy producing an error about forward references that are not defined in
the same module? Or is that a wrong approach somehow?

Here is my example code:

```python
from my_types import SomeXs

class X:
    pass
```

Type aliases are defined like so:

```python
# my_types.py
from typing import List

SomeXs = List['X']
```

When I run mypy, I get an error that `X` is not defined:

```
$ mypy module.py
my_types.py:4: error: Name 'X' is not defined
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Try `SomeXs = List[X]`

Comment: @HirushaFernando That gives a "name not defined" error.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. If class ``X`` is not in ``my_types`` (via definition or import), then ``X``, ``'X'``, and any other some such variation *cannot refer to it*. This has nothing to do with forward declarations, which address later bindings *in the same scope*. How do you expect MyPy to know that ``X`` means ``module.X`` and not some other ``X``? Are you looking for a ``TypeVar`` perhaps?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That points into an interesting direction, I hadn’t thought about the fact that mypy needs to know about the definition of the type I am referring to, not only that it’s called `X`.

Comment: If PEP 484 supported absolute rather than relative forward references (e.g., `module.X` rather than merely `X`), the obvious answer would be to use absolute forward references instead. Of course, PEP 484 doesn't, so you can't. The non-obvious answer is to [abuse `TYPE_CHECKING` as in fqxp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65265627/2809027), because *no* global variable is too obscure to be abused by mypy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’m gonna share the solution I found in the mypy documentation [common issues section](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html?highlight=TYPE_CHECKING#import-cycles) here: It is necessary for mypy to have access to the definition of `X`. To avoid an import cycle, the mypy
documentation recommends a trick - only import the definition that
would create a cyclic import when type checking. It goes like this:

```python
from typing import List, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from main import X

SomeXs = List['X']
```

This makes the Python interpreter ignore the import when executing
this code, but mypy still uses the definition of `X` from `main`.

Et voilá:

```
$ mypy *.py
Success: no issues found in 2 source files
```

Comment: I guess the documentation you refer to has now moved here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime_troubles.html#import-cycles

Answer (score 0):

Mypy needs to have referenced types in scope:

```
$ cat my_types.py 
from typing import List

from main import X

SomeXs = List[X]
```

And the code containing `X` doesn't reference `SomeXs`, so it shouldn't be imported there:

```
$ cat main.py 
class X:
    pass
```

The result:

```
$ mypy .
Success: no issues found in 2 source files
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was only the test case. I do need the SomeXs type in main.py, so this solution won’t help.